# How to merge modifications from specific revision to trunk sub-folders

Tags: svn, merge, branch, trunk

I have some files in my branch directory that I want to merge with the trunk. But want to do this only for a specific revision, and apply the modification for all sub-folders.

So, my files are located at "branch/src", but not only. There are files in "branch/src/visualization", "branch/src/test", and so on. What I want is to merge all the modifications of a single revision in "trunk/src" and its sub-folders.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- Merge subtree is Bad Idea (tm)
- `svn help merge` says, that merging single revision is `-c REV` option